# Representation of a binary variable

Tags: common-lisp, data-representation

How would you find out how SBCL (and perhaps other common-lisp compilers) represents a typed variable.  For example, SBCL translates a variable typed as `(member +1 -1)` into type `(or (integer 1 1) (integer -1 -1))`. But is this a bit, a fixnum, or maybe even bignum?

Comment: _Note to clarify a misconception in my initial question (above): variables do not have types. The lisp objects that variables (and other place references) point to, however, are typed. A better statement of the topic might be: Representation of the value of a binary variable._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well. It's easy to check:

```
(type-of 1)
; ==> BIT
(type-of -1)
; ==> (integer -281474976710656 (0))
```

So `-1` and `1` are of different types, however you have multiple inheritance in CL so it's true that `1` and `-1` are many many other types they share in common:

```
(typep 1 'integer)  ; ==> t
(typep 1 'fixnum)   ; ==> t
(typep 1 'number)   ; ==> t
(typep 1 't)        ; ==> t
(typep 1 'bignum)   ; ==> nil
(typep -1 'integer) ; ==> t
(typep -1 'fixnum)  ; ==> t
(typep -1 'number)  ; ==> t
(typep -1 't)       ; ==> t
(typep -1 'bignum)  ; ==> nil
```

And of course:

```
(typep -1 '(member +1 -1)) ; ==> t
(typep 1 '(member +1 -1))  ; ==> t
```

So only `1` is a bit, both are fixnum and none are bignums. The values are most likely stored in the pointer in the CL implementations that do that. Note that type has little to do with actual storage. Both values are most likely stored as a full machine word, in my case 8 bytes (64 bits), in the pointer. For a bignum you have the 8 bytes to point to a heap object that has allocated additional space for the actual value.

Comment: SBCL may have specialized storage for certain number ranges, for example in vectors. `(upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 1))`   -> `BIT`

Comment: @RainerJoswig So it might store bits more compact in vectors, but probably not OPs two alternative values which would require more mapping?

Comment: Basically a `(SIGNED-BYTE 8)` array.

Comment: @Sylwester, wonderful clarification (I think). So, each separate lisp object created by a program takes up a certain amount of memory (based on its type), and each variable created is a pointer (in the heap) to its object's memory location?

Comment: I think that multiple inheritance is not the right term regarding _types_, as it is a _class_ concept. What you are describing is subtype relationship and the conceptual difference between `type-of` and `typep`.

Comment: @davypough The pointer doesn't need to be on the heap unless it's represents a free variable to be captured in a closure and Rainer mentions that vectors can have an actual byte representation as a (space) optimization.

Comment: @Svante You mean `type-of` and `typep` won't work with classes in the same manner? A perfect language doesn't distinct special optimized (perhaps primitive) types with the custom user defined ones and CL does a good job at this.

Comment: No, they do.  It's all working OK.  It's just that you don't need _multiple inheritance_ in order to explain _subtype relationships_.  Don't confuse classes with types.  To illustrate subtype relationships, I wanted to point out that `typep` can return `t` for a lot of types, but `type-of` can return only one type.